# How to use custom template repository?

Tags: typesafe-activator

Starting the activator with **activator new** you get a list of project seeds and you also can get templates. Is it possible to have one's own source/repository of seeds and templates or is there a possibility to configure to not use the typesafe ones?

I want to achieve something like this:

```
$~- activator new

Fetching the latest list of templates...

Browse the list of templates: http://my-templates
Choose from these featured templates or enter a template name:
1) My-Own-Seed
2) CompanyConfiguration

(hit tab to see a list of all templates)
```

I know of **g8** but I don't want to use it because I like the tight integration with sbt of activator.

EDIT:
I found documentation at https://typesafe.com/activator/template/contribute but I'm not sure if I can achieve that the seeds are just usable within an enclosed environment.